# Looking for a collection of short horror fiction from the 80’s or early 90’s - was couched as for children

Tags: story-identification, horror

Excited to think someone may be able to help me here.
I’m looking for an anthology of stories - I believe there were 10-13 short stories which I read multiple times in 1991/1992 or 1992/1993. The three stories I remember vividly are:

Story 1: about the wendigo - where a hunting party ends up trapped out in the forest in a cave and one of the members starts eating the others and turns into a wendigo. May even have been partially what ravenous was based off. It is not the original Algernon Blackwood story.

Story 2: an old ‘woman’ rolls around the old west like a tumble weed looking for victims to attach herself to as a parasite. Once she’s on their back their only escape is to kill themselves.

Story 3: a scientist/alchemist creates a giant frog kind of like Gollum I think? The frog then ends up eating all his dozens of cats - the end of the story is the scientist starting to create cats to fight back.

Creepy stuff and certainly not appropriate for 11 year olds but hey - that’s what we had access to. I know it’s not scary stories to tell in the dark because I have all those. Any help would be much appreciated as I haven’t been able to track this down on my own.

Comment: There was a series "Scariest Stories you've ever Heard", maybe you're looking for one of them.

Comment: My first thought was the Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scary_Stories_to_Tell_in_the_Dark), which I think came out in the 80's and early 90's (there were 3 books). They were based on mythology, urban legends, folk tales, etc. 

There is a story of a Wendigo in the first book, but it grabbed the author's friend and took him at terrible speeds, burning off his limbs.

Comment: That one is based off Algernon Blackwoods' story so not that I wouldn't think.  Story 2 sounds familiar I might have read this but it's been 30 years, I checked a lot of horror short story collections out of my high school library...

Answer (score 4):

This is [*Monsters You Never Heard Of*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1308120), a collection of fourteen short stories by Raymond Van Over.

The book can be [borrowed from the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/monstersyounever00vano).

From the story "The Windigo"

> Light Wolf was shocked. “You don’t know yet? You don’t see it? You’re
> a *Windigo!* A flesh-eater. You even look different, you’ve become more
> beast than man. You’ll never be able to stop now. You will never die,
> but never again will you crave anything as much as human flesh.”

From the story "The Burr Woman"

> “What the hell is a Burr Woman?” someone asked.
>
> “She’s an old hag the Indians fear. There are legends that say once
> she gets on someone’s back nothing can get her off. No one knows where
> she comes from or anything about her. Except the Indians think she’s
> very powerful medicine.”

From the story "Nevillon's Toad"

> “Oh, my Lord,” Nevillon groaned. “Oh, my Lord. What have I done?”
>
> Now he knew. The missing cats had been food for the blue toad.
> Nevillon broke down and wept as the toad hopped over and looked up at
> him like a concerned puppy. It croaked once or twice in sympathy with
> its unhappy master. Then, getting no response, it went back to hunting
> the cats.